# In iPhone X and older can't back to previous View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, viewcontroller

I have some weird problem for me. I have ViewController with ScrollView. On iPhone 11, 11 Pro and 11 Pro Max when I slide finger to down it back to previous ViewController and when I slide to left or right nothing happens, when I slide to up by Scroll View scrolling down - That my app should work on all iPhones, but in all rest (iPhone 6,7,8,X etc.) it doesn't work! When I turn on my ViewController on for example iPhone X, and and slide down it bounce, and don't back to previous ViewController, when I slide left or right it bounce - it shouldn't bounce. When I slide to up ScrollView working well. Can anyone help me find solution to block bounce on left and right, and back to previous ViewController when slide down, when I'm on upper position of ScrollView?

This is how my ViewController should work
[image: App should work that]

This is how my ViewController is build.

[image]

One more photo

[image]

@Edit
I think problem is with ScrollView, because when I disable in View "User Interaction Enabled", than when I swipe down it back to previous ViewController, but off course than ScrollView don't work

Comment: What iOS versions are all those devices on? And how is the view controller presented?

Comment: Only from IOS 13+ `pageSheet` has become the default presentation style. on older devices the default presentation style is `fullScreen`. Make sure to set presentation style to `pageSheet` to get the desired effect

Comment: I'm using only iOS 13.3 in Symulator. I will add screen up. :)
In my settings users must have iOS 13+
@Cerlin, how to change it?

Comment: Go to project -> select target -> select `general` tab -> go to deployment info -> change target version

Comment: @Cerlin i have already iOS 13.0 + requirements. I changed Presentation for ViewController, but it doesn't fix anything. ;/

Comment: I think problem is with ScrollView, because when I disable in View "User Interaction Enabled", than when I swipe down it back to previous ViewController, but off course than ScrollView don't work.